# How to run "php artisan serve" on local network

Tags: laravel, vue.js, remote-access, laravel-artisan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSelw.png)Me and a classmate are working on an online shop. We must share our progress and started using Dropbox but it was too slow. We tried connecting our PCs through a local network, he shared the project in a "Public Access" folder so I can read and edit files but when I run the php artisan serve command I have this message saying UNC routes are not supported.
I have a similar problem with the npm run dev/watch because it searches for a file in "C:" but I'm not on C:

I tried changing the command to php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 and also changing the host and port as well but it didn't worked. Also tried to run both commands on PowerShell, I read that it support UNC routes but it threw the same error. I'm desperate 'cause it's been like 4 hours and the Dropbox files aren't ready. About the npm problem I didn't find a useful answer. Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for windows

```
php artisan serve --host your-ip-add --port 8000
```

e.g

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.001 --port 8000
```

For `linux` use

`sudo` before command

and try to be on same network

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, but it threw the same error. "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory"

Comment: you are runing your project in drop box and try to change port

Comment: netstat -ano|find ":port_no" use this command to find out port is in use or not

Comment: I have it duplicated in a dropbox folder but i'm not using it, it's still updating. I'm trying to run the artisan serve of the folder that's in my mate's computer, using our local network. 
Something like \\his-pc/path in my git bash, I also tried in PowerShell but the same error was threw, sorry again for the bad english

Comment: you can't run laravel project from public folder make copy of lt and run

Comment: thank you, I guess I'll have to do that or wait until dropbox finishes